# why my derived class is an abstract class? C++

Tags: c++, xcode, virtual, derived

```
//abstract product
class AbstractProduct
{
public:
    virtual void diplay(void) = 0;
};
//concrete product
class Histogram : public AbstractProduct
{
public:
    Histogram()
    {
        cout << "default construct a Histogram!" << endl;
    }
    void display(void)
    {
        cout << "Display Histogram!" << endl;
    }
};
//factury class
class Factury
{
public:
    static AbstractProduct* getProduct(string type)
    {
        AbstractProduct* absP;
        if(type=="Histogram")
        {
            Histogram his;// error, Variable type "Histogram" is an abstract class   
        }
        return absP;
    }
};
```

I have already implement the pure virtual function, but it still said my derived class is an abstract class. I do not know why.

Comment: Could you show us the compilation error? It usually says what's wrong.

Comment: You have a typo: `diplay` is not the same as `display`.

Comment: Using `override` keyword may help to out-spot the typo.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that these functions

```
virtual void diplay(void) = 0;
```

and

```
void display(void)
{
    cout << "Display Histogram!" << endl;
}
```

have different names. I think there is simply a typo.

Take into account that this static function

```
static AbstractProduct* getProduct(string type)
{
    AbstractProduct* absP;
    if(type=="Histogram")
    {
        Histogram his;// error, Variable type "Histogram" is an abstract class   
    }
    return absP;
}
```

also have no sense because it returns uninitialized pointer `absP`

Comment: perfect :), that should be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If that really is your code you have a typo

```
 virtual void diplay(void) = 0;
```

and

```
 void display(void)
```